# Is there a better and more efficient way to check if a parameter is in request data to apply to django query filter?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset

I am building a REST API using Django, in the views I want to query models based on an unknown quantity of fields (as supplied in the front end as required). Previously I have been checking every combination possible for the incoming parameters to see if they are in the request data - if so, apply them to the query. However as the number of possible parameters increase (one of my current projects has 6 possible parameters), the number of permutations becomes too large. Is there a more efficient way of achieving the below?

```
if 'A' in request.GET['A'] and 'B' in request.GET['B'] and 'C' in request.GET['C']:
    query_1 = model_1.objects.filter(a=request.GET['A'], b=request.GET['B'], c=request.GET['C'])

elif 'A' in request.GET['A'] and 'B' in request.GET['B']:
    query_1 = model_1.objects.filter(a=request.GET['A'], b=request.GET['B'])

elif 'B' in request.GET['B'] and 'C' in request.GET['C']:
    query_1 = model_1.objects.filter(b=request.GET['B'], c=request.GET['C'])

elif 'A' in request.GET['A'] and 'C' in request.GET['C']:
    query_1 = model_1.objects.filter(a=request.GET['A'], c=request.GET['C'])

elif 'A' in request.GET['A']:
    query_1 = model_1.objects.filter(a=request.GET['A'])

elif 'B' in request.GET['B']:
    query_1 = model_1.objects.filter(b=request.GET['B'])

elif 'C' in request.GET['C']:
    query_1 = model_1.objects.filter(c=request.GET['C'])
```

Edit: Should have specified what I meant by efficient...I wanted to find a way to cut down on the number of conditional statements. I found out that this is not possible in following post. I have now adopted Q query which has improved readability and reduced lines of code.
[1]: [How to write a Django filter query for multiple values selected from a form without many if statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74763810/how-to-write-a-django-filter-query-for-multiple-values-selected-from-a-form-with)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your code more readable and concise like this:

```py
query_1 = model_1.objects.filter(**{
    'A': request.GET.get('A'),
    'B': request.GET.get('B'),
    'C': request.GET.get('C'),
})
```

OR

```py
# Use this with caution, as it will pass all query params in your request to filter()
query_1 = model_1.objects.filter(**request.GET)
```

Comment: for the first point, would i still have to check if the value is in the request? Not all parameters will be present at all times.

Comment: No, you don't need to. The code chunk in answer will replace your mentioned code in question.